# Get selected node names into a list or tuple in Nuke with Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, nodes, nuke

I am trying to obtain a list of the names of selected nodes with Python in Nuke.
I have tried:

```
for s in nuke.selectedNodes():
    n = s['name'].value()
    print n
```

This gives me the names of the selected nodes, but as separate strings.
There is nothing I can do to them that will combine each string. If I
have three Merges selected, in the Nuke script editor I get:

*Result: Merge3 
Merge2 
Merge1*

If I wrap the last variable n in brackets, I get:

```
Result: ['Merge3']
['Merge2']
['Merge1']
```

That's how I know they are separate strings. I found one other way to
return selected nodes. I used:

```
s = nuke.tcl("selected_nodes")
print s
```

I get odd names back like node3a7c000, but these names work in anything
that calls a node, like nuke.toNode() and they are all on one line. I
tried to force these results into a list or a tuple, like so:

```
s = nuke.tcl("selected_nodes")

print s
```

*Result: node3a7c000 node3a7c400 node3a7c800*

```
s = nuke.tcl("selected_nodes")

s2 = s.replace(" ","', '")

s3 = "(" + "'" + s2 + "'" + ")"

print s3
```

*Result: ('node3a7c000', 'node3a7c400', 'node3a7c800')*

My result looks to have the standard construct of a tuple, but if I try
to call the first value from the tuple, I get a parentheses back. This
is as if my created tuple is still a string.

Is there anything I can do to gather a list or tuple of selected nodes
names? I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and it seems that my last
solution should have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you iterate over each node, you'll want to add its name to a list (`[]`), and then return that. For instance:

```
names = []
for s in nuke.selectedNodes():
    n = s['name'].value()
    names.append(n)
print names
```

This will give you:

```
# Result: ['Merge3', 'Merge2', 'Merge1']
```

If you're familiar with list comprehensions, you can also use one to make `names` in one line:

```
names = [s['name'].value() for s in nuke.selectedNodes()]
```

Comment: Perfect! This is eactly what I needed! I was trying some thing with empty arrays too and appending values to it but I wasn't doing it right. Stupid for loops always give me a hard time.

Comment: @jakenolan52 I noticed you unaccepted this answer. Was there something you felt it was missing that I could improve on?

Comment: no it worked perfectly! It was the last piece I was missing in the tool I was writing. I was showing a coworker Stack Overflow on my phone the other day and I might have hit it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
nodename = list()
for node in nuke.selectedNodes():
    nodename.append(node.name())
```